# parsing xml with xmlstarlet and specific attribute

Tags: xml, xpath, xmlstarlet

I've tried to use `xmlstarlet` and am having difficulty. I have the following XML feed.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<RESPONSE VERSION="L100" REQUEST="show volume-statistics">
  <OBJECT basetype="volume-statistics" name="volume-statistics" oid="1" format="rows">
    <PROPERTY name="volume-name" display-name="Name">VOL0</PROPERTY>
    <PROPERTY name="volume-IOPS" display-name="IOPS">100</PROPERTY>
  </OBJECT>
</RESPONSE>
```

I need to select the IOPS value where the name is equal to `VOL0` and print only the value of the volume-IOPS.

I have tried following Commands:

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -m "RESPONSE/OBJECT/PROPERTY/[@display-name='VOL0']" -v "RESPONSE/OBJECT/PROPERTY[@volume0IOPS] test.xml
```

Example Output

```
100
```

Comment: Always tell us which error messages you received. You should have realized that the parentheses are unmatched (by the shell that does not execute your code, but still waits for input). After fixing that, `xmlstarlet` would have printed a notice that your first XPath expression is invalid (the `/` before the predicate shouldn't be there).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do this with a single XPath expression, that retrieves the `<OBJECT/>` element which contains the "VOL0" name property, and then selects the respective IOPS property.

```
xmlstarlet sel -t -v '
  /RESPONSE/OBJECT[PROPERTY[@name="volume-name"]="VOL0"]
  /PROPERTY[@name="volume-IOPS"]' test.xml
```